# Displaying XML in JSF

Tags: xml, jsf, richfaces

I have a method that gives back a formatted XML string. I want to show that on a JSF page in a nicely wrapped, readable way. I used this solution first.

```
<pre><h:outputText value="myBean.xml"/></pre>
```

The result is indented, but it doesn't wrap very long lines (with a lot of attributes for e.g.)

RichFaces is also available in my project. What would you suggest?

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: "well-readable" is vague. An example of the output you're trying to achieve would help.

Comment: Sorry, my description really lacked info!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you right, but if it is a plain vanilla String with XML data which you want to display as-is in the JSF page, then the first logical step would be to escape the HTML entities so that it's not been parsed as HTML. You can use h:outputText for this, it by default escapes HTML entities (which is controllable by the 'escape' attribute by the way):

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.xmlString}" />
```

Or if it is formatted and you want to preserve the formatting, then apply the CSS white-space:pre property on the parent HTML element.

Or if you want to add syntax highlighting (colors and so on), then consider a Javascript library which does the task. Googling "javascript xml syntax highlighting" should yield enough results.

Comment: Thanks! I will give the credit to you. However I was looking for white-space: pre-wrap :)

Comment: Take care: pre-wrap doesn't work in IE up to with 7, nor in FF2.
Also see http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html